# Did the Prophet(pbuh) marry his wife "Maymunah" after the revelation of Quran 33:52?

Tags: nikah, prophet-muhammad, history, wife, surat-al-ahzab

With the verse ***Quran 33:52***, Muhammad(PBUH) was not allowed to take any new wives or change them for other wives.

> Not lawful to you, [O Muhammad], are [any additional] women after
> [this], nor [is it] for you to exchange them for [other] wives, even
> if their beauty were to please you, except what your right hand
> possesses. And ever is Allah , over all things, an Observer.
>
> according to chronological order of Quran this Surah revealed in  5 AH. [here](http://www.englishtafsir.com/Quran/33/index.html)

But according to history, the Prophet married "Maymunah bint al-Harith al-Hilaliyah" in year 7 AH (629 AC) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maymunah_bint_al-Harith).

**Question:**

Did the Prophet marry "Maymunah bint al-Harith al-Hilaliyah" after the revelation of Quran [33:52](http://quran.com/33/52)?

Comment: a little bit related.... [Did the Prophet marry any more wives after the revelation of 4:3?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/did-the-prophet-marry-any-more-wives-after-the-revelation-of-43)

Comment: Just as an explanation this Verse has been made void by (33:50) or (33:51) as they were revealed afterwards, but are placed before in the order of the Mushaf

Answer (score 3):

Yes, he married Maymunah bint al-Harith after the revelation of 33:50-52. This marriage was within the scope of 33:50. She **gave herself to the Prophet** in 7 AH when the Prophet visited Mecca to perform Umrah. Abbas (her sister's husband) also interceded for her. Therefore, the Prophet agreed to marry her.

> Prophet, We have made lawful for you the wives to whom you have given
>   their dowers, as well as those whom your right hand possesses from
>   among the captives of war whom God has bestowed upon you. and [We have
>   made lawful to you] the daughters of your paternal uncles and aunts,
>   and the daughters of your maternal uncles and aunts, who have migrated
>   with you; **and any believing woman who gives herself to the Prophet,
>   provided the Prophet wants to marry her.** This applies only to you and
>   not to the rest of the believers. We know what We have prescribed for
>   them concerning their wives and those whom their right hands may
>   possess, in order that there may be no blame on you. God is most
>   forgiving, most merciful. ([33:50](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/33:50))

I believe the question arose because **مِن بَعْدُ** has been interpreted as *'after [this]'*. However, it means *'other than [those]'* here i.e. the Prophet was restricted to marry only those women that fall under the categories mentioned in 33:50.